# Picasso load text after image is finish

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, picasso

I am working with picasso/recycle view basically in my recycle view I load an image and a description for that image.

What I need is to load the text after the image is complete, I was loading the text and the image at the same time.

**So i tried this:**

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(urlFoto)
        .resize(400, 400)
        .into(holder.plantPhoto, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d("SUCCCESSSSS", "SUCESSSS");
                holder.plantName.setText(plants.get(position).getSpecie());
                holder.plantCheck.setText("Penso que seja esta!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });
```

Now nothing gets loaded inside my recycle view, I don't know why, it doesn't even enter the success callback.

Comment: try setting the text in the onError() too. Maybe the download fails an the onSuccess is not called. Let me know if it works?

Comment: you are right it faills, but how can i see the error message?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do when the onError() is called?

Comment: @FilipeCosta Check whether your link is http or https . Picasso does not load images over http .

Comment: it loads because i already did it, without the callback it was loading

Comment: i want to see what the error is